# BDD android Test for Multiple flavored Android Application not working

Tags: android, android-testing, cucumber-jvm

I am testing an Android application which has product flavors using Cucumber framework(BDD).I am using Cucumber Instrumentation runner for running the features.I started testing for one of the flavor but I am getting the below error:

No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that our test runner expects (e.g. doesn't inherit from `TestCase` or lacks `@Test` annotations)

**Command** :

```
gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Dtags="@login"
```

Getting the below error:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.example.gviswa200.myapplication.cucumber.steps.StepDefinitions com.example.gviswa200.myapplication.flavor1.test/com.example.gviswa200.myapplication.cucumber.runner.CucumberTestRunner

Error:
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'cucumber.runtime.CucumberException'
Empty test suite.
```

I know the error is due to `CucumberTestCase.java` not being picked up by the runner `CucumberTestRunner`, resulting in `CucumberException`. But I did change the path of the `CucumberTestCase.java` file several times but still I am getting the same error.

This is my sample android project repo : 
 https://github.com/vsgopinath/AppWithFlavors

I have built the project based on the reference project :
 https://github.com/sebaslogen/CleanGUITestArchitecture

Let me know if further information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must place the test classes in a special folder for any flavor.

that's mean a folder with name androidTest[yourFlavorName]

for example  =>  ( androidTestPaid / androidTestFree )

2. You must run the tests with a special command for any flavor.

for example => ( gradlew connectedPaidAndroidTest / gradlew connectedFreeAndroidTest )